# How to connect multiple divs from path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using svg for connecting one div to multiple div. Currently i am able to get only 1 div connected but unable to connect other divs. I am applying `<path>`. For example I want to connect **div A to B** and **div A to C** and so on if there are **N** divs so **div A** must be connecting to **N divs**:

```js
const $b1 = $("#box1");
const $b2 = $("#box2");
const $line = $("line");
var path = document.querySelector(".path");
const padding = 7;
// Amount to offset control points
var bezierWeight = 0.675;
/* TweenLite.set($b1, { x: 400, y: 150 });
TweenLite.set($b2, { x: 200, y: 350 }); */
const coordinates = function() {
  const x1 = $b1.offset().left + $b1.width()/2-padding;
  const y1 = $b1.offset().top + $b1.height()/2-padding;
  const x4 = $b2.offset().left + $b1.width()/2-padding;
  const y4 = $b2.offset().top + $b1.height()/2-padding;
  var dx = Math.abs(x4 - x1) * bezierWeight;
  var x2 = x1 - dx;
  var x3 = x4 + dx;
  var data = `M${x1} ${y1} C ${x2} ${y1} ${x3} ${y4} ${x4} ${y4}`;
  

  /* $line.attr("x1", x1);
  $line.attr("y1", y1);
  $line.attr("x4", x4);
  $line.attr("y4", y4); */
  path.setAttribute("d", data);
}
coordinates();


$('#box1').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});

$('#box2').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});
$('#box3').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}


#box1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
}

#box2 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}

#box3 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 400px;
}

.path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: dodgerblue;
  stroke-width: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">A</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">B</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">C</div>

<svg height="1000" width="1000">
<path class="path" />  
  <!-- <line id="line" x1="400" y1="150" x2="200" y2="350" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width:1" /> -->
</svg>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
```

For making generic work i also tried to apply `$('.box').each(function(index, obj)` but eveytime i dont get anything. It would be thankful if my work goes in geneic way. Sorry for bad english, i am trying my best to explain my issue on ongoing work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you hardcoded the elements to be connected using a single variable for each one (`$b1` and `$b1`). I'd recommend grouping the string IDs of two connected boxes inside an object and ultimately bundling those objects inside an array.

So if **box1** is connected to **box2** and **box1** is connected to **box3**:

```
var connections = [{
  boxA: "#box1",
  boxB: "#box2"
}, {
  boxA: "#box1",
  boxB: "#box3"
}];
```

Inside the `coordinates()` function you're referencing another hardcoded element you've set up inside the html code: the svg `<path>`

Javascript has a built-in function to create elements on the fly `document.createElement()`. In this case however we need `document.createElementNS()` because we need to specify the svg namespace. Such an dynamically created element can finally be added to an existing element using `element.appendChild(elementToBeAdded);`

So the `coordinates()` function needs to be modified in such way that it first removes all existing paths, iterates over all the objects inside the connections array and creates and appends the required paths to your `<svg>`.

Here's an example:

```js
var paths = document.getElementById("paths");
const padding = 7;

var bezierWeight = 0.675;

var connections = [{
  boxA: "#box1",
  boxB: "#box2"
}, {
  boxA: "#box1",
  boxB: "#box3"
}];

const coordinates = function() {

  let oldPaths = paths.children;
  for (let a = oldPaths.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
    paths.removeChild(oldPaths[a]);
  }

  let x1, y1, x4, y4, dx, x2, x3, path, boxA, boxB;

  for (let a = 0; a < connections.length; a++) {
    boxA = $(connections[a].boxA);
    boxB = $(connections[a].boxB);

    x1 = boxA.offset().left + boxA.width() / 2 - padding;
    y1 = boxA.offset().top + boxA.height() / 2 - padding;
    x4 = boxB.offset().left + boxA.width() / 2 - padding;
    y4 = boxB.offset().top + boxA.height() / 2 - padding;
    dx = Math.abs(x4 - x1) * bezierWeight;

    if (x4 < x1) {
      x2 = x1 - dx;
      x3 = x4 + dx;
    } else {
      x2 = x1 + dx;
      x3 = x4 - dx;
    }

    data = `M${x1} ${y1} C ${x2} ${y1} ${x3} ${y4} ${x4} ${y4}`;
    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    path.setAttribute("d", data);
    path.setAttribute("class", "path");
    paths.appendChild(path);
  }
}

coordinates();

$('#box1').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});

$('#box2').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});
$('#box3').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#box1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
}

#box2 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}

#box3 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 400px;
}

.path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: dodgerblue;
  stroke-width: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">A</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">B</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">C</div>
<svg height="1000" width="1000" id="paths">
</svg>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks i am getting some clue. For making N divs i tried in this way:

https://jsfiddle.net/zohaibrehman/mut9y4va/151/

Comment: i ve shared the jsfiddle this is bit different as i was trying to get some dynamic results. If u drag any div u will see

Comment: Yeah this happens because you don't clear existing paths before appending new ones. This is what  `for (let item of paths.children) {
    paths.removeChild(item);
  }` in my code above does.

Comment: i applied ur way. Sounds like i am closer but my lines shows double line while moving.

Comment: also in ur code too this is happening. Can u plz check ?

Comment: Ah good catch. It didn't clear all the paths so there was always one left. I corrected the example code in my answer!

Comment: Thanks. Another thing A and B is making a beautiful curve whereas A and C are creating straight line whereas i am also trying to make a curve. Can u also look?

Comment: Well the control points for your bézier curve just fit if the connection goes to the left. You can compensate by adding a simple check on which side the target box actually is. I modified my code above once more.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend.I will make further improvements. If i need help regarding that i will  let you know. 

Regards